Calculating Average of last 10 Data Entries while Omitting Zeros
I am trying to create a tracking sheet for our local high school's target shooting team. My Google sheet will calculate the the average of all rounds shot. However, I am trying to write a formula that will only take the average from the last 10 entries while omitting any cells with a 0. Now Column AB5:AB42 will calculate the average for each row. In cell B3 it will calculate the average for all rounds. I would like for cell B3 to only calculate the last 10 entries while ignoring the zeros on the sheet. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
Tracking Sheet
I was able to calculate the average of all rounds in B3, but not been able to calculate last 10 entries while omitting zeros

Try this
=average(QUERY(tocol(A2:A,1),"select Col1 where Col1 !=0 offset "&if(COUNTIF(TOCOL(A2:A,1),"<>0")<10,0,COUNTIF(TOCOL(A2:A,1),"<>0")-10)))

Change the column references to your column numbers (listed here as A2:A).

Thank you that worked perfectly. The last thing I am trying to do is run a CountIf at the bottom of the column, which works. However, now I would like to run a CountIf for the last 10 entries as well. This is what I have for Column C =Countif(C5:C42,"X"). What can I use if I only want the last 10 entries instead of the entire column? Thanks again for the help!

I added a conditional to protect in the event less than 10 entries were present. I can't access the google document you linked, so going off your comment alone, it seems like you could try =COUNTIFS(QUERY(tocol(C5:C42,1),"select Col1 where Col1 !=0 offset "&if(COUNTIF(TOCOL(C5:C42,1),"<>0")<10,0,COUNTIF(TOCOL(C5:C42,1),"<>0")-10)),"X")

Thank you, but unfortunately I keep getting 0 as a result. I have made the document editable and you should be able to access it now. Any other suggestions?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vJsghBlBrUnuiVMehhhBM5TxgSeufBAaHIVOyuIGMPM/edit?usp=sharing

Oh it definitely helped to see the document. I updated it to be =COUNTIFS(QUERY(tocol(C5:C42,1),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null offset "&if(COUNTIF(TOCOL(C5:C42,1),"<>0")<10,0,COUNTIF(TOCOL(C5:C42,1),"<>0")-10)),"X") and it's working

You could try something the following using the query api:
=arrayformula( average( query( sort( A2:A, row(A2:A) * ISNUMBER(A2:A), false), "limit 10", 0 ) ) )

This does not omit zero values but you can probably achieve this by tweaking the query
Reference:

https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

